# What happened to Kylo Ren?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

At the end of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* we see two related events:

> Rey defeats Kylo Ren in combat, but there is no clear indication that he died. His wounds appear to be to extremities or other non-vital areas such as his shoulder. This leads me to believe he is still alive, and primed to turn mechanical like his grandfather did four movies prior after being defeated in a lightsaber fight with Obi-Wan. This is speculation, as the movie is not specific here.

Also:

> Snoke tells General Hux to grab Kylo Ren and flee the planet so Kylo Ren can complete his training.

However, there is no visual indication about what happens to Kylo Ren after the final events on the planet. We see the Millennium Falcon leaving, but no other ships.

Did Kylo Ren leave the planet with General Hux at the end of the film? Is there any canon answer in the novelization or other sources?

Comment: ... wait for Episode VIII?

Comment: @randal'thor but I don't wanna!

Comment: The fact that Snoke even requests Kylo be brought to him is a pretty good indication that Kylo is still alive and made it off the planet.  JJ would not have thrown that into the story if Kylo was dead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree, I am wondering what evidence there is to support it. If you read the first spoiler tag I have my own speculation about why he survives.

Comment: Whoever VTCed as "opinion based" - please note that this has fully objective answer, in novelization, as OP asked.

Comment: @randal'thor  - Episode VIII: Lens Flares Flare Back

Comment: @DVK that is why I asked for canon answers, not random internet opinions. If I wanted speculation, I can down a few beers and come up with my own random theories.

Comment: One movie before, not four?

Comment: @JackBauer Episode 3 (7-4) showed Aniken suffer major injuries and turn into Darth Vader.

Comment: @Snowman THat is 4 movies before: 4,5,6,1,2,3,7. Episode 3 is 1 movie before 7 :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

I re-watched the film. No screenshots yet but the very last film moments before the chasm opens show Ren lying on the snow, rising to a half-sitting position **with his torso facing the screen square-on**. His hand is clearly still attached and moving (he raises his forearm before raising the torso). He is clearly all in one piece and not dead nor Anakined.

---

The novelization says the following:

Kylo Ren's condition:

> ... Unarmed, he raised a hand and utilized the Force to fend off one slashing blow after another, until finally her fury penetrated his remaining defenses. **Taking a glancing blow to the head and chest, he went down, a prominent burn slashed across his face**. Weakened, he reached out toward his lightsaber, trying to draw it to him.

He was clearly alive, that wound doesn't sound terribly awful nor Anakin-style-limb-losing.

And Rey refused to finish him off. As we all know from Dark Helmet, evil will always win, because Good. Is. Dumb.

> One downward cut, she saw. One quick, final strike, and she could kill him. The landing lights of a shuttle appeared in the distance, coming over the trees in her direction. She had to make a decision, now.
>   Kill him, a voice inside her head said. It was amorphous, unidentifiable, raw. Pure vengeful emotion. So easy, she told herself. So quick.
>   **She recoiled from it. From the dark side.**

So what happened to Kylo Ren then?

> A deep gully formed, separating her from General Hux and the arriving troopers. Utilizing the tiny position sensor emplaced in Ren’s belt, Hux had tracked him to this spot. He would have taken Rey and Finn, as well, if not for the command that had been issued by the Supreme Leader. That took precedence over everything. There was simply no time left.
>   The two renegades were going to die here anyway, he told himself as he **followed the troopers carrying Ren into the nearby shuttle. As soon as he was aboard, it lifted off, its occupants desperate to flee the dying planet**.

So, they left.

Hux did that on Supreme Leader Snoke's direct orders, so Snoke clearly had further plans for Ren:

> In the darkness of the cavernous assembly room, Hux stood before the image of Snoke. Try as he would, it was proving increasingly difficult to maintain a semblance of control.
>   “Supreme Leader, the oscillator is failing. The collapse has begun.” He looked downward. “There is nothing that can be done.”
>   Furious as he was, Snoke knew there was nothing he could do. So many plans so carefully laid, so many intentions that must now go unfulfilled…
>   “You will leave Starkiller at once **and come to me with Kylo Ren**. Leave immediately.” He added grimly, “It appears that he may have been right about the girl.”

Comment: So the novelization _does_ describe another part of that scene with the chasm in the forest. It breaks to the Millennium Falcon rising above the ridge, but does not show General Hux's shuttle. The movie is unclear, but this helps. Thanks!

Comment: "Anakinied". That's actually what I expect to happen. Him throwing himself to the pit that formed after the fight, to BE like Darth Vader was.

Comment: "Good. Is. Dumb." -- I'm not sure that applies here. Acting on a Dark-Side impulse may push the killer/executioner over the edge themselves, creating a new (worse?) threat. Failing to kill the enemy (cf Ep 3ff) may make them more determined/hateful, thus even stronger. Walking away leaves the enemy alive -- for the time being -- but keeps the person's integrity intact (important for a soon-to-be Jedi) and may yet plant a Light-Side seed in the opponent, neutralizing some of the threat. (The way I understood the movie, Rey *knew* that Kylo had issues and was not through-and-through evil (yet).)

Comment: @raphael she called him a "monster" ...

Comment: Maybe she used her brain in the critical moment, maybe not. Just saying not killing may be the smart move here.

Comment: If I ever utilize the verb "utilized" in a work of fiction, please utilize a baseball bat on me. "Unarmed, he raised a hand and utilized the Force" - Ugh! :P

Comment: @DanJ - i'm sure new Disney canon also has synergy and strategize and leverage.